# The function "else" in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I am having some difficulty in using the function `else` in R.
When I input `?else`, I didn't get any help about the function `else`.

When I run the following program:

```
i=1

if(i>1){print("aa")}

else{print("bb")}
```

the `else` didn't work. Can someone tell me the reasons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to get help type

```
?'else'
```

look at the paragraph in help

> Note that it is a common mistake to forget to put braces ({ .. }) around your statements, e.g., after if(..) or for(....). In particular, you should not have a newline between } and else to avoid a syntax error in entering a if ... else construct at the keyboard or via source. For that reason, one (somewhat extreme) attitude of defensive programming is to always use braces, e.g., for if clauses.

```
if(i>1){print("aa")
}else{print("bb")}
```

or

```
if(i>1){print("aa")}else{print("bb")}
```

will presumably work for you.

```
i=1

{
if(i>1){print("aa")}
else{print("bb")}
}
```

would also work. The key is to let the parser know to expect more input.

Comment: Best to keep away from one liners unless it's only a a short if with a simple result e.g. if(a==1){doSth()} otherwise stick to this syntax: http://ideone.com/sl56C